# Getting the page number?

Tags: operating-system, page-numbering, page-size

I wanted to know how to get the page number in the following exercise:

The page number of the 24-bit address 0x654321 that has 256 bytes page size is:
A) 0x21
B) 0x65
C) 0x6543
D) 0x4321

I think the answer is letter C but I am not sure why. Could anyone tell me how to solve these types of exercises?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

```
   0x654321  / 256
```

Just integer division on using the page size.